# Why are params undefined when sending a DELETE request in my next.js (version 14.1.4) app?

Tags: typescript, next.js, prisma

I have a DELETE mapping here

```
export async function DELETE({params} : {params: {id: string}}) {
    try {
     const loanToDelete = await prisma.loan.findUnique({
        where: { id: parseInt(params.id) }
     })

    if (!loanToDelete) {
    return NextResponse.json({message: "Loan not found"}, {status: 404})
    }

      await prisma.loan.delete({
        where: {id: loanToDelete.id}
      })
      return NextResponse.json({message: "Loan successfully deleted"}, {status: 200})
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
      return NextResponse.json({message: "An error occurred"}, {status: 500})
    }
  }
```

That seems to be unable to read params for some reason.

Testing this endpoint in Postman : `http://localhost:3000/api/loans/27` just gives me

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
```

Which to me is odd since I have a GET mapping that is essentially the same as above (except i'm simply finding an object and returning it)

```
export async function GET(response: NextResponse, {params} : {params: {id: string}}) {
    try {
        const loan = await prisma.loan.findUnique({
            where: {id: parseInt(params.id)}
        })
        if (!loan) {
            return NextResponse.json({message: "Loan not found"}, {status: 404})
        }
        return NextResponse.json(loan, {status: 200})
    }
    catch {
        return NextResponse.json({message: "An error occurred"}, {status: 500})
    }
}
```

It works perfectly fine in retrieving the id from params. Is Next.js unable to read params in DELETE request the same way as a GET request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `DELETE` function also accepts both `Response` and `params` arguments. Therefore, you must accept the `params` as the 2nd argument same as the `GET` function:

```
export async function DELETE(_, {params} : {params: {id: string}}) {
     ...
}
```